# Distribution of distinct objects into distinct groups

Tags: combinatorics

I came across this question on the principle of distribution under combinatorics:

> "Find the number of ways in which 6 different prizes can be
> distributed among 3 children, each receiving at least 1 prize."

Assume that all the prizes have to be distributed.
So, basically I could solve this by dividing it into cases as $(1,1,4)$ for when A gets 1 prize, B gets 1, and C gets 4 prizes, $(1,2,3)$ and $(2,2,2)$ and then calculated distributions in each case as well as taking into account the unique arrangements, as $(1,1,4)$ and $(1,4,1)$ are 2 different cases. By adding all of them, I arrived at the answer 540, which is the correct answer according to the solution in the book.
However, I tried attempting to do this by taking the total number of ways to distribute 6 prizes among 3 children without any conditions, and then subtracting the cases where even any one of them got no prize, but failed to arrive at the solution. So, what I did was this:

Total ways to distribute 6 prizes among 3 children without any conditions:
$3^6$
This also includes the case $(0,0,0)$. So,
$3^6 -1$ 
Now let any one child get no prize and so 6 prizes can be distributed among 2 children in 2^6 ways. And we can select the child getting 0 prize in 3 ways. So,
$$3^6-1-3(2^6)$$
However $3 * 2^6$ ways has 3 cases of $(0,0,0)$ which we had already excluded earlier, so we should add 3 now.
$$3^6 -3(2^6) + 2$$
Also $3 * 2^6$ has 2 cases each of $(0,0,1)$, $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, so by following earlier reasoning we must add 3 to the expression as these cases are getting subtracted twice.
So, final expression becomes
$$3^6 - 3(2^6) + 5$$
But this gives the answer 542. I can't point out exactly where I went wrong and I would really appreciate it if someone could.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making basic errors in applying inclusion-exclusion, eg $3^6$ includes all ways of **actually** distributing each object to someone, thus correct application would be

$3^6 -\binom31 2^6 +\binom32 1^6 =540$

Comment: Yes, now I understand my mistake. I did not apply the inclusion exclusion principle correctly. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome ! $\;\;$ :)